# Why OkHttp if I can use Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I know that similar question has been asked but somehow I did not find the answer I am looking for.

I use Retrofit 2.2 and I make some simple calls to the server. Everything works but now I don't know why and when do I need to use OkHttp?

I know that Retrofit uses internally Okhttp, but still I did not include OkHttp in my gradle, and I don't know which version of OkHttp is retrofit using for his calls now?

When and why do I need to include OkHttp in my gradle and make calls directly with OkHttp? if with retrofit everything works fine (for my calls) why should I use OkHttp?

What OkHttp gives me additionally that I don't have with retrofit and vice versa?

Comment: "why should I use OkHttp?" -- not everything is a Web service, and not everything needs to be parsed as part of a response. I would not use Retrofit for downloading an image or a Web page, for example. Retrofit makes invoking a Web service and parsing its response easy, but that is not the only scenario for HTTP operations.

Comment: @CommonsWare but for example, for downloading an image I heard about Picasso, but again why should I use OkHttp over picasso for downloading? basically I can make the app using Picasso and Retrofit and without actually using OkHttp directly. In which occasion would you use OkHttp?

Comment: "but again why should I use OkHttp over picasso for downloading?" -- for images, I would use Picasso. "In which occasion would you use OkHttp?" -- downloading Web pages, ZIP archives, PDF files, or anything else that is not an image (use Picasso) and is not going to be parsed into memory (use Retrofit). And I would plug OkHttp into both Picasso and Retrofit, so that I can configure my HTTP setup (proxies, SSL, etc.) once.

Comment: @CommonsWare for video whould you use Picasso? with plug OkHttp you mean something like Retrofit.client(MyOkHttpClient) for example?

Comment: "for video whould you use Picasso?" -- no, as Picasso cannot handle video. "with plug OkHttp you mean something like Retrofit.client(MyOkHttpClient) for example?" -- yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare so for video i should go directly with OkHttp?  
I have one more difficulty... how can I log requests that I send with retrofit? I found something like Okhttp Interceptor... So for logging things I need to use OkHttp? there is no way without it?

Comment: OkHttp does HTTP requests. Retrofit does APIs over HTTP (and uses OkHttp). Picasso does image loading, and you can plug in OkHttp for loading images over HTTP. ExoPlayer does video playback, and you can plug in OkHttp for loading videos over HTTP. If you only want to log Retrofit API calls, you can do that. If you want to log everything that goes through OkHttp (including Retrofit and whatever else), you can add an interceptor there.